# Is flexibilise a word?

Tags: vocabulary

Is flexibilise a word?
Some dictionaries say yes, but it is not a word I commonly see on internet.

If not, which word could I use?

Examples:
My manager is thinking about flexibilising my work schedule.
In my company, they have flexibilised the dress code for Fridays.

Comment: It seems to have a [fairly limited usage within economics and the topic of labor relations](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22flexibilize%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en). I would personally avoid it outside of those contexts.

Comment: OP, you discuss a common situation but then bust out a super-rare word. Why?

Comment: I think you misunderstand how dictionaries work. It seems inconceivable you've actually found any dictionary *explicitly* claiming that ***fexibilise / flexibilize*** is not a valid word". It's regularly formed (allowing for the US/UK spelling difference) - it's just nowhere near as common as structurally similar derived forms such as ***plasticise, criticise, romanticise,...*** Dictionaries don't always list every possible derivation, but that doesn't mean they're claiming anything they *didn't* include in the dictionary is "not a word".

Comment: In latin languages, the correspond to flexibilise is very common. That is why I think it could be used in other languages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to Merriam Webster, it is a word, but not one I have ever heard used. Spell checkers also mark it incorrect. In general, there is probably a better word or phrase to use for almost any occasion. One that comes to mind for the dress code example is *relax*, as in, "In my company they have relaxed the dress code on Fridays", as for the first, I think you would more commonly phrase it as "My manager is thinking about making my work schedule more flexible". *Relax* would also work in that case, as in "My manager is thinking about relaxing my work schedule", but that might come across as working less hours than before, rather than just shifting hours as implied by flexibility.

Comment: Thank mate. Very useful.